# Printing TEXt in IFRAM in html

Tags: html

How to print text in IFRAME in html? my code is here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a">
Hello How are you and show me now

</iframe>

<p><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="iframe_a"></a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

the above text is not shown in IFRAMe how can i add that

Comment: That's not how you use an iframe...

Comment: An iframe is used to display a web page within a web page.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that make a html file and put some text in that file let consider in our case your file name is htmlframe.html and embed that file with iframe like

```html
<iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="htmlframe.html" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple text can not be added on an iframe as the content of the iframe will be overridden by the src specified. So try this trick .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VkzVgiYUEIM" name="iframe_a">

</iframe>

<span style="position:absolute;z-index:99;font-size:50px;color:RED;margin-top:-200px;">YOUR LABEL HERE</span>

</body>
</html>
```